# is it safe to delete log/system.log and log/exception.log files from var/log folder

Tags: magento-1.7

I want to remove system.log and exception.log files from log folder and i want to know is this safe or it may stop system to work. please help and inform me as soon as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.. It is safe. But remember the following thing before you are going to delete those files.

1. Those files note the errors that are caused at server level or database level.
2. Those files contains the Exceptions that are caused at any module or extension level.
3. On production, some used to disable this exception functionality from the Admin. Once this is disabled, then no data will log to these files.
4. On enabling this Log Functionality, Site loading time gets increases.

Finally, if you dont want any previous error messages or log data, You can delete those files as per your wish.